# Showing that a logarithmic inequality holds

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

Given $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < 1$, how can I show that the following inequality holds:

$$
\frac{1}{R(x_1, x_3)}+\frac{1}{R(x_2, x_4)}<\frac{1}{R(x_1, x_2)}+\frac{1}{R(x_3, x_4)}
$$
where $R(x, y)=\log(1+S(x,y))$ and

$$
S(x,y)=\frac{-x-y+\sqrt{a x^2y+(x+y)^2}}{2x}
$$
and $a\ge 1$ is a constant.